# DataTable Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My datatable plugin is not working and i dont know why please help...

when trying to debug the javascript on Google crome i found this error and i know if they are clashing

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined localhost:49769/Scripts/main.js:1
Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found localhost:49769/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js:1
'Range.detach' is now a no-op, as per DOM (http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-detach).

Am using MVC5 to develop the application

this is the main Js

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $("#customers").DataTable();
});
```

});

```
<!-- add new calendar event modal -->
<!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/main.js"></script>
<!-- DATA TABES SCRIPT -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.10.3 -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/jqueryKnob/jquery.knob.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- iCheck -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/AdminLTE/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="/Scripts/Template/js/AdminLTE/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
```

this are all my script reference

Here is the Table

```
    <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <br />
                <div class="box-header row-fluid">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="span2 pull-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Enable</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Disable</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                    <table id="customers" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
                                <th>Customer Name</th>
                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Location</th>
                                <th>Registration Date</th>
                                <th>Customer Status</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
                                <td>Mike Ebon</td>
                                <td>0802647281243</td>
                                <td>mike@yahoo.com</td>
                                <td>Surulere Lagos, Country</td>
                                <td>10/13/2014</td>
                                <td><span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
                                <td>Mike Ebon</td>
                                <td>0802647281243</td>
                                <td>mike@yahoo.com</td>
                                <td>Surulere Lagos, Country</td>
                                <td>10/13/2014</td>
                                <td><span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
                                <td>Mike Ebon</td>
                                <td>0802647281243</td>
                                <td>mike@yahoo.com</td>
                                <td>Surulere Lagos, Country</td>
                                <td>10/13/2014</td>
                                <td><span class="label label-danger">Denied</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            </div><!-- /.box -->
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that before or after your script tag that includes jQuery?  Make sure it's after.

Comment: it after but it isn't responding still

Comment: Does it work if you replace `jQuery` in the JS with $?

Answer (score 0):

According to Datatables.net

> DataTables has only one library dependency (other software upon which
>   it relies in order to work) - jQuery. Being a jQuery plug-in,
>   DataTables makes use of many of the excellent features that jQuery
>   provides, and hooks into the jQuery plug-in system, in the same way as
>   all other jQuery plug-ins. jQuery 1.7 or newer will work with
>   DataTables, although typically you will want to use the latest
>   version. DataTables includes everything else that it requires to
>   operate.

Update your jQuery to the newest version and try again. Also remove the

```
jQuery(function ($) {
});
```

in the main JS. You don't need it.